# Memory Error when plotting images using loops python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I have a lot of images that I am plotting for data quality control purposes. I am using nested loops to go through and extract the gzipped files and then plot and save the images as .png so they can later be referred to. I can get it to run for a while but eventually I will get a Memory Error. I don't know if I am making a dumb mistake, any help is appreciated.

I have tried making temp folders to extract the gzipped files to and then removing them. I have also tried closing all the plots after I make them each time in the loop, however I still get a memory error after running it for a while. I did some googling and an issue with flushing and fsync, as well as the fact that the gzipped files are on a NTFS formatted external hard drive, but that is where I get lost.

Below is the my relevant code:

```
while len(thelist) > 0 :
    temppath = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    os.chdir(temppath)

    tpath = thelist.pop()

    myextractor.myextract(tpath)

    paths = glob('*HRV')+glob('*.IR120')+glob('*.WV73')+glob('*.VIS8')+glob('*.VIS120')+glob('*.VIS6')+glob('*.IR16')

for x in range(0, len(paths)):
    #get the files and paths correct
    spath ='/' + paths.__getitem__(x)
    spath1 = spath.replace('\\','/')
    spath = temppath+ spath1
    spath = spath.replace('\\','/')

    r = 0
    r=McIdasObject.McIdasImageFile(spath)
    #the semi colon is important ..maybe

    fig = plt.imshow (np.array(r));

    #most of this is just getting the correct file and path name
    strpath = str(temppath)
    strpath = strpath.replace('c:\\users\\appdata\\local\\temp\\','/')
    folder = tpath[20]+tpath[21]+tpath[22]+tpath[23]+tpath[24]+tpath[25]+tpath[26]+tpath[27]+tpath[28]
    newpath = savepath + '/' + folder
    if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
        print 'saving:' + newpath + spath1 + '.png'


    plt.savefig(newpath + spath1+ '.png')
    r=0
    plt.close("all")


    gc.collect()
os.chdir(destin)
if len(paths) < 1 :
    badimages.append(temppath)
else:
    shutil.rmtree(temppath)
```

This is the trace back

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-1-22dce83b27e3>", line 1, in <module>
  runfile('C:/Users/Alex/Documents/Python Scripts/image printer.py', wdir='C:/Users/Alex/Documents/Python Scripts')
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
  execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
  exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/Alex/Documents/Python Scripts/image printer.py", line 57, in <module>
  plt.savefig(newpath + spath1+ '.png')
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 577, in savefig
  res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1476, in savefig
  self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 161, in print_figure
  FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2211, in print_figure
  **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 521, in print_png
  FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
  self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1085, in draw
  func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2110, in draw
  a.draw(renderer)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 373, in draw
  im = self.make_image(renderer.get_image_magnification())
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 597, in make_image
  transformed_viewLim)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 219, in _get_unsampled_image
  x = (x * 255).astype(np.uint8)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your question. Where are you getting the MemoryError? Please add a traceback from when it happens to your question.

Comment: okay I am running the code now to get the error,

Comment: Try putting all but the last line of the code in the `for x in range(0, len(paths)):` loop into a separate function and call it in the loop followed by a `gc.collect()` call. Returning from the new function will deference all the local variables defined in it and which may allow the garbage collector to do a better job.

Comment: I will work that into the code and see if it works

Comment: You should also move the `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` to inside the separate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example that's the same as your problem. On my machine, this causes ipython to use up all the memory and then crash:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for ii in np.arange(1000):
    fig = plt.imshow(np.random.random([1000,1000]))
```

(Next time, if you can figure it out, try to provide an example like this that's as small as possible, removing all nonessential code).

Rather than recreating a figure every time, try creating the figure once and re-using it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.imshow(np.random.random([1000,1000]))
for ii in np.arange(1000):
    fig.set_data(np.random.random([1000,1000]))
```

Comment: Okay Thanks, I will try that tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: So I tried re-using the figure, and all my output images got messed up, for reference the images are 2500,2500 or 3725,3725 or 5000,5000 or 11300, 11300. It did not work for any of them. Also when I put "plt.close('all') after the "fig = plt.imshow(np.random.random([1000,1000])"  the code does not crash...?

Comment: I also just tested at the 5000,5000 dimension and it did crash, so I will continue to work on it